# A KCQL error occurred. Can't flatten from schema:Schema{ARRAY} by selecting 'flexibleattributes'

Tags: json, apache-kafka, cassandra, schema, apache-kafka-connect

ERROR There was an error writing the records A KCQL error occurred. Can't select an element from an array(schema:Schema{ARRAY}) (com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.connect.cassandra.sink.CassandraJsonWriter:172)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A KCQL error occurred. Can't select an element from an array(schema:Schema{ARRAY})
at com.datamountaineer.streamreactor.common.converters.ToJsonWithProjections$.raiseException$1(ToJsonWithProjections.scala:43)

{"schema":{"type":"struct","fields":[{"type":"array","items":"string","optional":true,"field":"flexibleattributes"}],"name":"costedevent","schemaName":"orctocassandra","optional":false},"payload":{"flexibleattributes":["2","9123456780","0522610111","00:04:36","0","1","0035526724053","","Locali","Fast Voice SCR 2010","01:01:01","","0","1","0","0","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""]}}

please give the solution